# Как разобрать строку на ассоциативный массив

Tags: php

Как правильно разобрать строку на ассоциативный массив?

Есть строка `p1-tuttext-p2-555-p3-text-p4-text3`

Ее нужно превратить в массив вида:

```
p1 => tuttext
p2 => 555
p3 => text
p4 => text3
```

Как это сделал я:

```
$new_fields = [];//новый массив
$p = 0;//объявляем новую переменную, для добавления значения в массив
$fields = explode('-', $fields);//преобразуем всю строку в массив
foreach ($fields as $field) {//перебираем массив
  if($p) {//проверяем есть ли ключ в переменной p
    $new_fields[$p] = $field;//если есть добавляем ключ и значения в новый массив
    $p = 0;//обнуляем переменную для ключа
  }
  if(stristr($field, 'p')) {//проверяем вхождение `p` в строке
    $p = $field;//если есть, то это у нас ключ, добавляем его в массив
  }
}
```

Есть ли более простой способ?

----upd----

В свете новой информации:

- `p1-tuttext` - `p1` это подстановка буквы + id, который может быть
  вплоть до 99999 (`p99999`)
- `p1-tuttext` - `tuttext` это название в
  транслите и может встретиться в виде tut-text(`p1-tut-text`)

Был выбран вариант Vfvtnjd:

```
$string = 'p1-tuttext-p2-555-p3-text-p4-text3';

$pattern[] = '/(.|$)p(\d+)(.|$)/i';
$pattern[] = '/p(\d+)(.|$)/i';

$replacement[] = '&p$2=';
$replacement[] = 'p$1=';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

parse_str($result, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Строка вида [p12345-tut-lubou-text-p999-a-tut-drugoy](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5eeab1b1620e7d405ad4d65b03a84f29cc5d0af) разобрана

Comment: а обязательно проверять? "проверяем вхождение `p` в строке", так бы можно было резать по "-p" а потом по "-"

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh, не обязательно, главное разграничить, что `p` идет в ключ, а после `p` идет в значение

Comment: Как сделать чтоб это работало? )) $data='p1-tuttext-p2-555-p3-text-p4-text3';
$data='"'.$data.'"';
$data2=str_replace('-', '""', $data);
$data3=str_replace('"p', ',"p', $data2);
$data4=str_replace('""', '"=>"', $data3);

$data5=substr($data4, 1);
$data6=array($data5);
print_r($data6);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = 'p1-tuttext-p2-555-p3-text-p4-text3';

$pattern[] = '/(.|$)p(\d+)(.|$)/i';
$pattern[] = '/p(\d+)(.|$)/i';

$replacement[] = '&p$2=';
$replacement[] = 'p$1=';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);


parse_str($result, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: по моему достаточно `/(?>^|-)(p\d+)-/` заменить на `&$1`, или нет?

Answer (score 3):

если предположить, что ваши ключи-значения чередуются, то можно разбить сначала по дефису, потом на пары, а потом сложит в массив

```
$str = "p1-tuttext-p2-555-p3-text-p4-text3";
$values = explode("-", $str);
$chunks = array_chunk($values, 2);
$data   = array_column($chunks, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений разбить строку на массив подстрок, которые в свою очередь разбить на пары "ключ=>значение", и подставить их в результирующий массив:

```
$str = 'p1-tuttext-p2-555-p3-text-p4-text3';

preg_match_all('~\w{2,}-\w+~', $str, $arr);
$result = [];
foreach ($arr[0] as $item) {
    list($key, $val) = explode('-', $item);
    $result[$key] = $val;
}

print_r($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [p1] => tuttext
    [p2] => 555
    [p3] => text
    [p4] => text3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну и ну =)

```
<?php
$data='p1-tuttext-p2-555-p3-text-p4-text3';
$data='"'.$data.'"';
$data2=str_replace('-', '""', $data);
$data3=str_replace('"p', ',"p', $data2);
$data4=str_replace('""', '"=>"', $data3);

$data5=substr($data4, 1);

$data6=eval('return ['.$data5.'];');
print_r($data6);

?>
```